# Could you please identify this weed in my lawn?

Tags: lawn

I live in Fairfield, CT. I've noticed a particular type of grassy weed starting to pop up in my lawn which is actually from last year but very noticeable from this year. Now that it's May, 2018. I'd like to identify it so that I can learn how to prevent it from spreading further.

It's a lighter green color than the rest of my lawn. Please see the pics.

I really appreciate your comments![image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like what I thought was alfalfa grass that I planted as a winter cover crop in a bed this past year. Searching online and it does seem like it's a variety of grass, perhaps just different from what you're used to.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have searched online more based on alfalfa grass.. Is it maybe orchard grass?  Please see below link for the pics. https://extension.umass.edu/landscape/weeds/dactylis-glomerata

Comment: Yeah, seems like it could be orchard grass.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  So no selective herbicides work for these kinds of grass weeds.. I learned a lot from a long research yesterday. I read in another post regarding using non-selective herbicides with cotton gloves over chemical gloves.  Kind of painting each weed.  I am going to try over the weekends.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the pictures, location and probability my best guess is Elymus Repens aka "QuackGrass"

It's an invasive plant, that is now found in all but 7 states in the US. Fairly common and pretty annoying.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Can you please check pics in below link? I now know this is one of the most difficult weeds to control in a turf. ..https://extension.umass.edu/landscape/weeds/dactylis-glomerata

Comment: Not quackgrass. Seedhead is wrong, no overlapping auricles.